# Wso2esb rest to soap - uri-template is appended to receiving esb

Tags: api, rest, soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I have two wso2esb instances:

1) receives a rest uri-template and sends it as a soap request.
Example request: http://myipadd:8280/restcontext/mypath

2) receives and process the soap request from #1.

When I log the request from #1, it logs that my header "To: /services/MyService" is set correctly as expected. But when I receive it from #2, it appends the path: "To: /services/MyService/mypath".
Now, my proxy service is not able to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this before sending soap request to remove your REST_URL_POSTFIX:

```
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
```